# "cannot read property 'fileName of undefined'" error while uploading file to Google Drive using a html form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The script started to throw an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileName' of undefined at uploadFile(Code:16:25)

It was working a couple of months back, but now it doesn't, also it sometimes works when used in some other sheet.

Also this is not my code, and i am not a tech guy, i just used this code of someone else. if you could help please tell me what changes do i make in this code.

```
/* this is the index.html used to get the file to upload*/

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_center">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="myForm" >
    Select File:
    <input type="file" name="myfile" accept="*" /><br>
    File name: <input type="text" name="fileName" /><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="upload(this.parentNode);" />
  </form>
  <script>
   window.onload=func1;

  function func1() {
   document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });  
  }

   function upload(obj){
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(close).withFailureHandler(close).uploadFile(obj);
   }   

   function close(e) {
       console.log(e);
       google.script.host.close();
   }

  </script>
</body>
</html>


/* code.gs function called when file is uploaded*/ 
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('File')
      .addItem('Attach...', 'showForm')
      .addToUi();  
}

function showForm() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Upload File');
}

function uploadFile(obj) {
  var newFileName = obj.fileName; //this is where debug shows the above error
  var blob = obj.myfile;
 
  var upFile = DriveApp.getFolderById('1BWcs7RBPDyJQm_R0FLEUxCfRlKTB0uwX').createFile(blob).setName(newFileName);
   var fileUrl = upFile.getUrl();
  var urlCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
 urlCell.setValue(fileUrl);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### There seems to be a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/149980602) related to the curent upgrade of the Apps Script runtime to [v8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime)

- While this is being fixed, you cannot [disable V8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_rhino_runtime) by going from the Apps Script Editor on 
  `Run -> Disable new Apps Script runtime powered by V8`
- You can alternatively use a different method to upload your file

Sample how to upload your file with fileReader:
*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_center">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="myForm" >
    Select File:
    <input type="file" name="myfile" accept="*" /><br>
    File name: <input type="text" name="fileName" /><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="upload(this.parentNode);" />
  </form>
  <script>
   window.onload=func1;

  function func1() {
   document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });  
  }

 function upload(obj){
   var file = obj.myfile.files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(e) {
    var obj2 = {
      fileName: obj.fileName.value,  
      mimeType: file.type,
      bytes: [...new Int8Array(e.target.result)]
    };
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(close).withFailureHandler(close).uploadFile(obj2);
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
   }   

   function close(e) {
       console.log(e);
       google.script.host.close();
   }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*code.gs*

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('File')
      .addItem('Attach...', 'showForm')
      .addToUi();  
}

function showForm() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Upload File');
}

function uploadFile(obj) {
  var newFileName = obj.fileName;
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(obj.bytes, obj.mimeType, newFileName);
  var upFile = DriveApp.getFolderById('1BWcs7RBPDyJQm_R0FLEUxCfRlKTB0uwX').createFile(blob);
   var fileUrl = upFile.getUrl();
  var urlCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
 urlCell.setValue(fileUrl);
}
```

**Note:**

Your error message `TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileName' of undefined at uploadFile` implies that you tried to run the function `uploadFile` manually form the editor - without passing it a file as `obj` parameter - this will lead to the error since without a file there is no `fileName` (and no fiel data).
The way your code is designed, `uploadFile` needs to be called from the html form after you upload a file.